# redirect does not work htaccess joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

hi have this site in joomla (`www.example.com/site3/`) and i need to redirect to another joomla site (`www.anotherexample.com/site3/`)

`www.anotherexample.com` is a web site and `www.anotherexample.com/site3/` is another web site

In `www.example.com/.htaccess` i put this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^site3\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.anotherexample\.pt\/site3\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

If i remove the file `www.anotherexample.com/site3/.htaccess` the redirect works, but the links do not work on the site and displays 404 error

How can I make this work?

Comment: is "site3" and not AFP

Comment: ok what URL do you see in the browser after redirect which is is causing 404?

Comment: the redirect doesn't work if i do not remove the (www.anotherexample.com/site3/.htaccess). But if i remove, i have 404 just reloading the page

Comment: Can you provide us `anotherexample.com/site3/.htaccess`?

Comment: Do you have this .htaccess in `www.example.com/site3/.htaccess` OR in `www.example.com/.htaccess` OR in `www.anotherexample.com/site3/.htaccess`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/A7TvBhUH

Comment: I just wanted to know where is this htaccess located and on which server?

Answer (score 1):

You musn't escape your target website, nor wrapping it between quotes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^site3(?:\/(.*)?)?$ http://www.anotherexample.pt/site3/$1 [R=301,L]
```